# When can I negotiate a raise?

Tags: united-states, negotiation, salaried-pay

I work for the state therefore when I was hired I was assigned a pay rate with no negotiations. In the range I was told, the higher would be ok but the lower not so much so I risked it and accepted the position because it’s perfect for me. Well, my job duties have quickly expounded and I am producing much more than expected. However, I just found out the probationary period is a whole year. I can’t live off the pay with benefits being taken out. Can I negotiate after 90 days even though I’d be still in probationary period?

Comment: which state, what country?

Comment: Louisiana, United States

Comment: There is never a wrong time to ask for a raise.  Just know that you may not get it.  Its as simple as that.  Do you think companies don't like to make more money during the year?  Or do you think they too wait X amount of days to invoice say a new client?  Everyone wants to make money: you, them, and every other business out there.  Sometimes you make it other times you dont.  If you dont choose your next job / client / etc.

Comment: "Can I negotiate after 90 days even though I’d be still in probationary period?"  What does your contract say?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Answer (score 3):

> Can I negotiate after 90 days even though I’d be still in probationary
> period?

You can but be prepared to at the very least hear "no" and possibly erode relations with your boss. Especially as you are still on probation you can be very easily removed from the post, very much as soon as they will find someone willing to do your job for similar money but without the possibility of surprising raise requests. I would tread carefully.